# Fastest Non-Blocking Infinte Loop?

Tags: javascript, loops

The title basically says it all, but I will give context so that alternative solutions to my hypothetical problem can be presented.

I'm looking to build a game loop that can be a concern separated from the display refresh rate. My goal is to loop faster than the 16ms per loop given by `requestAnimationFrame`.

One suggested solution which works fairly well but is still not (I hope) the fastest possible is the obvious `setInterval(loopFunction, 0)`, which on my machine typically clocks in around 4ms per loop.

Ideally it would be something like an infinitely recursing function with tail-call optimization or a `while (true)` that doesn't block the UI thread.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You can't. There's only one thread. (disregarding worker threads for a second)

Comment: Refactor away from an infinite loop and make the entire thing eventful or reactive.  Why do you need faster than 4ms?  Are you using an integrator step for physics or something?  You will still need to be able to handle slow downs.

Comment: @zero298 The architecture is indeed reactive, "time passed" is the event and it requires a loop to be raised

Comment: you could run multiple setIntervals at the same time, might get it down to 1ms or less?

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer The existence of only one (UI) thread does not necessarily mean I can't get a loop faster than 4ms, although the lack of a 'yield' keyword or similar might but I'm unaware of it hence the question

Comment: That's indeed the problem. You can make a really fast loop, but if it never returns then the event handler never runs, so you can't get any interaction with the user.

Comment: I was going to try and come up with some kind of answer, but even with [`performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now), I don't think you'll be able to get timestamps of a high enough resolution especially after Spectre.  However, with node.js, you may be able to get high resolution stamps using [`process.hrtime()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time).  I was able to measure ticks of ~600ns (unless I'm doing it wrong).

Comment: Why would you want to build a game loop that runs faster than the refresh loop, and why would you want to build a game loop that maxes out CPU? Notice that you will need to code your game loop in a way so that it can run at different speeds anyway, so having it run at "normal" speed must work regardless whether there's a faster way or not.

Comment: @Andrew Or you could just put a `for (var i=0; i<4; i++)` inside the 4ms-`setInterval`.

Comment: @AndrueAnderson you can't block the event thread. So there's that. There's no yield, there's only `setInterval`. Unless you use workers, you need to do all game logic in the event loop, prepare for a repaint and then use `requestAnimationFrame`. Pair that with a frame rate limited and you have all the CPU you want.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer Thanks for the comment! I don't think I fully understand what you meant, but the 'game loop' is actually not really a loop as the architecture for my toy engine is fully reactive based on the FRP paradigm. The loop I'm asking to speed up here is actually just a loop that emits my main "time passed" event (/signal) - the faster I can get this loop the higher the resolution of my game's simulation. e.g. position, velocity, and acceleration values can be updated more frequently and will thus have smaller 'steps'. So I'm really looking to decouple that loop from frame rate.